# AJAX page loading but DIV not expanding to fits its content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load in AJAX content into an empty but the div won't resize to the size of the content being loaded. Instead it looks like its overlapping the empty div like with a z-index affect.

Are there some guidelines on setting divs?

this is my set up:

My XHTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="content-fill">
            <div id="files_left_pane">static content</div>
            <div id="files_right_pane">ajax content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 955px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-right: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
}
#content-fill { }
#files_left_pane { float: left; height: 100%; }
#files_left_pane { float: left; height: 100%; }
```

This is the code that handles the AJAX:

```
    function cabinet_tabs(){

        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $("#files_right_pane > .tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
        //On Click Event
        $("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li").live('click', function() {
            $("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $("#files_right_pane > .tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
            return false;
        });
        $("#files_right_pane > table.zebra tr:even").addClass('alt');

        // AJAX
       $('.view-prospects').live('click', function(){
       $.post('resources/ajax/ajax.php', {
           action : 'prospects',
           uid : uid
       }, function(data){
           $('#files_right_pane > #prospects').html(data);
       });
     });
    }
```

UPDATE:

maybe I should point out that I have this js code that loads in my navigation pages via ajax and resized the #main-contnet div to fit the content. Within that #main-content div the #content-fill is loaded in from those links.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hash Change and delegation of menu links
//------------------------------------------------------------------
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();
$(".nav_profile_menu > a.hash").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    newHash = window.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#content-fill")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #content-fill", function() {
                    $pageWrap.animate({
                        height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                    });
                    cabinet_tabs();
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(900);
                });
            });
    };
});
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

does this have any affect?

Comment: @s2 , did you give a try with overflow property's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding `overflow:hidden;` to your `#content-fill` div.  This will force it to expand to hold the floating left and right child divs.

For a related example [see my answer on this other S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357981/how-do-i-get-a-div-to-wrap-around-floating-children/4358006#4358006)

Answer (score 0):

s2xi,

if child is not occupying the parents width try this

```
#files_left_pane { float: left; height: 100%; width:100% }
```

if that looks bad try

```
overflow:scroll// it will show scroll barks
```

Comment: also its not occupying the parents height, which is my issue

Comment: @s2xi , then give 100%width on child elements ,it will definetly occupy the parents width

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the ajax content in a new div and set the height of content-fill and files_right_pane to height: auto;

Thanks for the tips and help guys